# Java String On Screen Push Down

Tags: java

I'm new to stackoverflow. I have this question for Java, though, and there might be a simple way to do it but I don't know how.

Here is my problem. I have my game, on the press of a button (X), to display text on the screen under the title of the top left of the game. That works fine, but lets say I have multiple. If I press N which could be the fifth one, it puts it what looks like random on the screen. But if I have all the buttons pressed, it will look normal, because all will be in line with each other.

Here is the code I have to write a line under the title of the game.

```
    var8.drawStringWithShadow("Test", 2, 11, 0xFFFF);
```

The first parameter is the text, second is x, 3rd is y.

Now, I have it drawing another one at the press of another key.

```
    var8.drawStringWithShadow("Test2", 2, 20, 0x008B);
```

As you can see, the y parameter was incremented by 9, so it would be under the other one.

What I want to do, is have the Y always be the same (11), But, if text is already there, push it down.

So lets say I had "Test" being displayed. But then I press the button to enable "Test2", and I want it to take the place of "Test", but not overrite it, when it is pressed, if "Test", or any other buttons are enabled, it will increment the y of "Test" or another one by 9.

I hope there is a simple way to do this, if there is, please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a counter for how many strings are there and let
`y = counter*9 + 11`